# Android ant: Build release with Debug option

Tags: android, eclipse, debugging, in-app-purchase, code-signing

I need to build my android app with my release `keystore`, because I need to test some in-app purchase stuff. However it would be super nice to debug it with eclipse (juno).

So is there a simple way to do that or have anybody created an ant script to do that?

I guess I must set `android:debuggable="true"` in the android manifest file and build / sign my app with the release key. How can I connect the eclipse debugger with this built Version of my app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, directly in Eclipse, without ant:

To enable debbuging to your build do the following:

1. Add android:debuggable="true" in your Android Manifest file:
2. Disable propguard in your project.properties file by removing the path to your proguard config: 
   proguard.config=${sdk.dir}/tools/proguard/proguard-android.txt:proguard-project.txt
3. Now build your project like a normal release with eclipse by doing a right click on your Project -> Export -> Android -> Export Android Application and follow the export wizard (set release keystore, keyalias, password etc.)
4. Upload your created APK to your device and install it (you may have to uninstall your previous app version, if the previous one is not signed with the same release key)
5. Start your App
6. Open the DDMS Perspective in Eclipse (Window -> Open Perspective)
7. In the DDMS Perspective you will see a list with all apps that are running on your device and are debuggable too. Select threre your app (the name is the package name) by clicking on it.
8. Click on the green bug icon (on the top of the list of all running debuggable apps) to connect the eclipse debugger to your app

now your app will stop and opens the debugger perspective, when you reach a breakpoint.

Answer (score 0):

Hello If u need to debug the in App purchase use the testing account made for the developer ...

as we had to give item id for buying the paid version 
give the item id as 
    `BillingController.requestPurchase(PurchaseApp.this,"android.test.purchased");`